# Use template class to bundle type metadata c++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a number of data types, which have some metadata related to them, say table_size and format. I want to get this metadata using a template lookup, i.e

```
struct C1
{}
struct C2
{}    
enum class Format
{
    Format1,
    Format2,
};

template<typename T, int A, Format F>
class DataTypeMeta
{
    constexpr int table_size = A;
    constexpr Format data_format = F;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    void Configure(Format f, int sz);

    template<typename T>
    void UploadData(std::vector<T> data){...}
} 
template<typename T>
Bar foo(vector<T> data)
{
   Bar obj;
   obj.Configure(DataTypeMeta<T>::format, DataTypeMeta<T>::table_size);
   obj.UploadData(data);

   return obj;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<C1> data;
  foo(data);
}
```

How can I implement this DataTypeMeta class or specialize it for the type C1, C2 etc

Comment: Why? You could easily add `table_size` and `data_format` to `C1` and `C2` without any extra classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to want to implement traits in some way:
see
https://accu.org/index.php/journals/442
http://www.info.univ-angers.fr/~richer/ens/div/traits_et_policy.php
http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/template_specialization_traits.php
for more explanation (or search about traits)